# Context based chunks using Adobe PDF Extract Python

Tags: python, extract, adobe, chunking

So, recently I came across adobe pdf extraction API, I'm using python and for those who aren't aware of adobe's extraction methods, given a PDF the API returns back the extracted text with each paragraph/text/list as a JSON object with its corresponding styles and even coordinates and path, what I'm trying to accomplish is to make context chunks from this json generated file but I want to be able to detect all headers and sub headers in the pdf, how can I go on about this?

Link to the complete JSON file: [JSON File](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-shadow-gczdyq?file=/src/data.json)

Edit:

This is the adobe extract api which extracts text from pdf:

```
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.auth.credentials import Credentials
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.exception.exceptions import ServiceApiException, ServiceUsageException, SdkException
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.execution_context import ExecutionContext
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.io.file_ref import FileRef
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.pdfops.extract_pdf_operation import ExtractPDFOperation
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.pdfops.options.extractpdf.extract_pdf_options import ExtractPDFOptions
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.pdfops.options.extractpdf.extract_element_type import ExtractElementType
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.client_config import ClientConfig

import logging
import shutil

import os.path
import zipfile
import json

# zip_file = "./ExtractTextInfoFromPDF.zip"


zip_file = "./ExtractTextInfoFromPDF.zip"

if os.path.isfile(zip_file):
    os.remove(zip_file)

input_pdf = "./microbe-guide-rtc/AutoTagOutput-tagged.pdf"

try:
    base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('__file__')))
    client_config: ClientConfig = ClientConfig.builder(
    ).with_connect_timeout(10000).with_read_timeout(10000).build()

    credentials = Credentials\
        .service_principal_credentials_builder()\
        .with_client_id('')\
        .with_client_secret('')\
        .build()

    execution_context = ExecutionContext.create(
        credentials, client_config=client_config)
    extract_pdf_operation = ExtractPDFOperation.create_new()

    source = FileRef.create_from_local_file(input_pdf)
    extract_pdf_operation.set_input(source)

    extract_pdf_options: ExtractPDFOptions = ExtractPDFOptions.builder() \
        .with_element_to_extract(ExtractElementType.TEXT) \
        .with_get_char_info(True) \
        .build()
    extract_pdf_operation.set_options(extract_pdf_options)

    result: FileRef = extract_pdf_operation.execute(execution_context)

    result.save_as(zip_file)

    print("Successfully extracted information from PDF. Printing H1 Headers:\n")

    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'r')
    jsonentry = archive.open('structuredData.json')
    jsondata = jsonentry.read()
    data = json.loads(jsondata)
    for element in data["elements"]:
        if (element["Path"].find("/Text")):
            print(f"="*50, "\n",element.get("Text", None))

except (ServiceApiException, ServiceUsageException, SdkException):
    logging.exception("Exception encountered while executing operation")
```

It produces a json file which is quite big, but here's a sample of the JSON:

```
{
    "version": {
        "json_export": "192",
        "page_segmentation": "5",
        "schema": "1.1.0",
        "structure": "1.1065.0",
        "table_structure": "5"
    },
    "extended_metadata": {
        "ID_instance": "2C D4 05 C8 70 B8 B2 11 0A 00 67 45 8B 6B C6 23 ",
        "ID_permanent": "46 30 20 41 30 20 30 30 20 43 38 20 37 30 20 42 38 20 42 32 20 31 31 20 30 41 20 30 30 20 36 37 20 34 35 20 38 42 20 36 42 20 43 36 20 32 33 20 ",
        "pdf_version": "1.6",
        "pdfa_compliance_level": "",
        "is_encrypted": false,
        "has_acroform": false,
        "is_digitally_signed": false,
        "pdfua_compliance_level": "",
        "page_count": 8,
        "has_embedded_files": false,
        "is_certified": false,
        "is_XFA": false,
        "language": "EN-US"
    },
    "elements": [
        {
            "Bounds": [
                140.27999877929688,
                692.2284545898438,
                474.11688232421875,
                720.9082183837891
            ],
            "CharBounds": [
                [
                    140.27999877929688,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    147.28524780273438,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    147.29959106445312,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    154.4805908203125,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    154.43995666503906,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    157.38265991210938,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    157.38267517089844,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    164.31118774414062,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    164.2825927734375,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    169.65196228027344,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    169.68263244628906,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    172.1421356201172,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    172.1421661376953,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    177.1930389404297,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    177.12167358398438,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    184.55516052246094,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    184.56179809570312,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    190.754638671875,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    190.7545928955078,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    193.214111328125,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    193.26243591308594,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    198.4671173095703,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    198.48240661621094,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    205.6634063720703,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    205.62168884277344,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    211.79257202148438,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    211.80239868164062,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    221.40989685058594,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    221.4022979736328,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    224.34500122070312,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    224.3450164794922,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    229.79112243652344,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    229.9251251220703,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    235.37123107910156,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    235.38555908203125,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    238.32826232910156,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    238.32827758789062,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    245.5751190185547,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    245.5883331298828,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    252.5935821533203,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    252.60902404785156,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    255.0685272216797,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    255.0685577392578,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    260.9209442138672,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    260.8891296386719,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    266.2584991455078,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    266.22877502441406,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    272.42161560058594,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    272.4084014892578,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    282.0158996582031,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    282.00828552246094,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    284.95098876953125,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    284.9510040283203,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    290.39710998535156,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    290.4707336425781,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    292.93023681640625,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    292.9302673339844,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    299.59523010253906,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    299.58970642089844,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    305.4421081542969,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    305.4695739746094,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    311.3219757080078,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    311.2901611328125,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    315.94580078125,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    315.96990966796875,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    318.91261291503906,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    318.9126281738281,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    324.732177734375,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    324.7321014404297,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    331.39707946777344,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    330.5515899658203,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    335.9976806640625,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    336.0120086669922,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    338.9547119140625,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    338.95472717285156,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    346.3882141113281,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    346.3882751464844,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    353.63511657714844,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    353.64833068847656,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    358.8529968261719,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    358.8090057373047,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    361.2685089111328,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    361.26853942871094,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    366.3194122314453,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    366.2491455078125,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    373.6826171875,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    373.68927001953125,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    379.8821105957031,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    379.86888122558594,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    382.3283996582031,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    382.3284149169922,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    391.9359130859375,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    391.9283142089844,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    394.8710174560547,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    394.87103271484375,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    400.6905822753906,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    400.6905059814453,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    406.8833465576172,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    406.7504425048828,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    414.1839294433594,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    414.19056701660156,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    421.6240539550781,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    421.6306915283203,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    427.8235321044922,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    427.7510223388672,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    434.7562713623047,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    434.8310089111328,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    441.4959716796875,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    441.49046325683594,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    448.7373046875,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    448.7505187988281,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    451.6932067871094,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    451.69322204589844,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    456.8979034423828,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    456.8528137207031,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    466.46031188964844,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    466.45269775390625,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    471.6573791503906,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    471.6573028564453,
                    705.6679840087891,
                    474.11680603027344,
                    720.9082183837891
                ],
                [
                    154.80653381347656,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    161.73504638671875,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    161.70645141601562,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    167.07582092285156,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    167.0460968017578,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    173.54637145996094,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    173.5869598388672,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    178.95632934570312,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    178.92662048339844,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    183.58226013183594,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    183.36700439453125,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    190.8004913330078,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    190.86642456054688,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    196.71881103515625,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    196.68699645996094,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    202.05636596679688,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    202.0859375,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    209.0144500732422,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    209.014404296875,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    211.47390747070312,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    211.50686645507812,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    218.6878662109375,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    218.64614868164062,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    223.850830078125,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    223.80682373046875,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    226.74952697753906,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    226.74954223632812,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    233.9963836669922,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    234.0095977783203,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    241.0148468017578,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    241.03028869628906,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    243.4897918701172,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    243.4898223876953,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    250.4950714111328,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    250.50941467285156,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    255.8787841796875,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    255.85015869140625,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    263.0970001220703,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    263.1695098876953,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    268.53887939453125,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    268.5695495605469,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    274.0156555175781,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    274.0299835205078,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    276.97267150878906,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    276.9727020263672,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    282.79225158691406,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    282.79217529296875,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    285.2516784667969,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    285.251708984375,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    290.62107849121094,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    290.5924530029297,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    297.83929443359375,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    297.8514099121094,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    304.8566589355469,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    304.8721008300781,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    307.81480407714844,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    307.8148193359375,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    315.06166076660156,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    315.0748748779297,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    320.4442443847656,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    320.4156188964844,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    325.7849884033203,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    325.81565856933594,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    332.0084991455078,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    331.9952850341797,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    334.93798828125,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    334.93800354003906,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    342.1848449707031,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    342.19915771484375,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    349.20440673828125,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    349.21875,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    351.6782531738281,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    351.67828369140625,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    358.8592834472656,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    358.8186492919922,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    366.06549072265625,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    366.0787048339844,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    373.00721740722656,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    373.03900146484375,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    378.4083709716797,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    378.378662109375,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    384.5714874267578,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    384.5714569091797,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    387.0309600830078,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    387.0782012939453,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    392.6561584472656,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    392.65611267089844,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    395.1156311035156,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    395.1156463623047,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    400.9352111816406,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    400.9351348876953,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    405.9860076904297,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    405.9750213623047,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    412.16786193847656,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    412.15464782714844,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    414.61415100097656,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    414.6141815185547,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    420.46656799316406,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    419.71446228027344,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    426.3794403076172,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    426.43431091308594,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    432.62713623046875,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    432.49424743652344,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    437.9403533935547,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    437.9535827636719,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    440.4130859375,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    440.4131164550781,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    445.99107360839844,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    446.0536193847656,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    451.63157653808594,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    451.63153076171875,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    457.20948791503906,
                    707.4687042236328
                ],
                [
                    457.20945739746094,
                    692.2284545898438,
                    459.66896057128906,
                    707.4687042236328
                ]
            ],
            "Font": {
                "alt_family_name": "Calibri",
                "embedded": true,
                "encoding": "WinAnsiEncoding",
                "family_name": "Calibri",
                "font_type": "TrueType",
                "italic": false,
                "monospaced": false,
                "name": "XWYBVT+Calibri-Bold",
                "subset": true,
                "weight": 700
            },
            "HasClip": false,
            "Lang": "en",
            "Page": 0,
            "Path": "//Document/H1",
            "Text": "GUIDE FOR SUBMITTING PERMIT APPLICATIONS FOR MICROORGANISMS DEVELOPED USING GENETIC ENGINEERING UNDER 7 CFR PART 340 ",
            "TextSize": 10.979995727539062,
            "attributes": {
                "LineHeight": 13.5,
                "SpaceAfter": 13.75,
                "TextAlign": "Center"
            }
        },
}
```

Each extracted text will be the same as that object with diff coords and charBounds as well

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm going for a more broader solution, it won't only be for this document, I'll have other documents as well that I may or may not know its specific headers' formatting, will those stylings and header detection remain consistent throughout most of the PDFs? I'll link the complete JSON file converted so you could gain more insight about this

Comment: There is an auto-tag way in adobe to tag a pdf not quite sure yet if tags will spot all headers or not, but could you please elaborate on your point? I got the part where most pdfs will basically have all fonts the same or different in weight or just different font names, so what makes it a unique identifier to spot a header?